# Quickest general strategy for village meeting

Tags: geometry, optimization, recreational-mathematics

Here is a problem, which neither I nor my friends (very experienced in solving things like this) can't solve. But it was used for a competition several years ago and one guy solved it there, as far as I know. Unfortunately the solution (and the guy) is lost.

> You have a village. It is shaped as a square 1 by 1. The headman lives at the exact center of the square. Other houses are spread throughout the area of the village, and there is only one person per house. There are finite number of houses, they all have size 0 and everyone is aware of their placement.
>
> The headman needs to organise a meeting, which collects all villagers. To do this, he goes to some other house and tells about the meeting, then go to the another, etc. Each villager is of course is guaranteed to be found in his house; once informed, he can either participate in the gathering or go to the meeting place at the headman house. They all travel at the speed of 1 and it takes 0 time to inform someone, once you've reached his(-er) house.
>
> You need to find the minimum time $T_{\text{MinMax}}$ in which all villagers (including headman) can be collected at the centre of village, regardless of their number and initial placement.
>
> The answer should come together with proof, i.e. you need to:
>   a) provide a strategy (who goes where) and prove that it will work for any village in time $t \le T_{\text{MinMax}}$
>   b) prove that for all other strategies there must a village, which will be "collected" in time $t \ge T_{\text{MinMax}}$.

Can anyone here solve it?

You can be sure, that $T_{\text{MinMax}} < \infty$. For example, the following strategy works in $T_{\text{Max}} < 3\sqrt{5}+3\sqrt{2}/2$:
1) The village area is divided into 4 square subareas 0.5 by 0.5.
2) The headman goes to a closest house in one subarea and assings its host to be a subheadman and asks him to do the same strategy in his subarea.
3) Then the headman goes to another, neighboring subarea and does the same. And repeats this with the rest of 2 subareas.
4) The headman comes back to the centre of village.
5) If some subarea has no houses inside the headman just skips it.
Let's say that in the worst case scenario it will take time $X$. Then for subheadmen it will take time $X/2$. The first subheadman is assigned in at most $\sqrt{2}/2$ time, the next in $\sqrt{2}/2+\sqrt{5}/2$ and the last in $\sqrt{2}/2+3\sqrt{5}/2$. Then at time $\sqrt{2}/2+3\sqrt{5}/2+X/2$ the last subarea is collected it its center and in $\sqrt{2}/4$ time it can be at village center. Which means $X < \sqrt{2}/2+3\sqrt{5}/2+X/2+\sqrt{2}/4$. So $T_{Max} = X < 3\sqrt{5}+3\sqrt{2}/2$.

It is easy to prove that $T_{\text{MinMax}} \ge 2+\sqrt{2}$ (consider a village with 4 houses in the corners), and I am almost sure that $T_{\text{MinMax}} = 2+\sqrt{2}$, it was the result of that guy from the competition.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but is there a constraint on the size of the houses? Can they not be made arbitrarily small and placed around the headman's house? Also, are we assuming that the headman takes no time to tell them about the gathering?

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on where $2+\sqrt{2}$ came from please? I've been trying it for about an hour now and if I've understood the problem correctly, it seems insanely hard. The fastest time I've got for houses at the corners of the unit square, centre $(0.5,0.5)$, so far is $1+2\sqrt{2}$, which is about $0.4$ more than your conjectured minimum.

Comment: @Jam When there are four houses, one at each corner: the headman goes first to one corner. Then the headman goes to one adjacent corner, and the resident of the first house goes to the other adjacent corner. Then (for simplicity) they both travel to the final corner (directly opposite of the first house.) Then everyone goes to the center. Total distance for headman: $2 + \sqrt 2$.

Comment: @YakovShklarov It seems obvious now that you point it out lol. I was trying to do an exhaustive search to no avail.

Comment: In $3$ dimensions, with one house at each cube vertex, a similar route costs $3 + \sqrt 3$. Perhaps there is a pattern, since $1 + \sqrt 1 = 2$ is clearly the minimum for the $1$-dimensional case, as is $0 + \sqrt 0 = 0$ for $0$ dimensions.

Comment: @Jam, size of the houses is 0. Headman takes 0 time to inform someone once he've reached his house. The houses can be placed around the headman house, but I don't see any point to consider this, it will always work.

Comment: @klm123: Why can't there just be one house, arbitrarily-close to the headman? Is this somehow prevented by the fact that "other houses are spread throughout the area of the village" (whatever that's supposed to mean)?

Comment: @Blue, there can be one house, there can be even 0. You need a strategy, which will work for all cases.

Comment: @kim123: Then what does "minimum is $2+\sqrt{2}$" mean? How can any one (non-zero) value be "the" answer? With just one house (or none), the time to gather everyone can be made arbitrarily smaller than any (non-zero) value you care to name.

Comment: We need the _worst-case minimum_. The best-case minimum is of course 0.

Comment: Surely if we have any minimum time, we can add a large but finite number of houses to increase that minimum?

Comment: @Jam, if you have a "minimum time" and you are able to construct a village, which can't be gathered in this time than this is not the minimum time, which the problem asks you to find. Please reread carefully: "You need to find the minimum time in which all villagers (including headman) can be collected at the centre of village, **regardless of their (houses) number and initial placement**". It is also have been rephrased few time in the comments.

Comment: @klm123 That's precisely what I'm saying though. It seems as though you can construct a set of houses whose minimum gathering-time is arbitrarily high; in which case, there is no minimum. Could we not make some approximation of a fractal where the villagers would each have to travel an arbitrarily long distance?

Comment: @Jam, after some point it is more villages you have - more easy to gather them, since they can help you. The problem is to figure out and describe a general strategy.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: In other words, **maximize the minimum time**. That makes sense. My problem seems to have been that I kept reading "[F]ind the minimum time [...] regardless of [...] number and [...] placement" as asking for the ("global") minimum *over all possible scenarios* ---best-case, worst-case, whatever--- which makes for a decidedly-uninteresting puzzle. Even now, I have difficulty interpreting the stated instructions as "Find the worst-case minimum." Thanks for cutting through my brain-fog. :)

Comment: Can you tell me why your previous method dosen't allow  to achieve $2+\sqrt(2)$?

Comment: @Matta, no, I can't.

Comment: @klm123 I was asking because you said **you know** your method doesn't work, and I was wondering if you actually disproved it.

Comment: @Matta, ah, you are talking about the method, which I've edited out? You can prove it doesn't work with an example of a village with a long string, which curves into a spiral around the centre.

Comment: @klm123 Can you provide some details? I actually made a simulation of the problem,and your method in fact doesn't produce the best time always (in cases when you randomly pick a house), but it works other times and never exceeds $2+\sqrt2$ for all random and my own custom setups of the village so far. But those were villages with $<100$ houses and unlikely contained a specific spiral, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Matta, spiral, the distance between neighbouring turns being Epsilon. Houses are placed along the spiral in groups, the distance between groups being Epsilon/10. Each group (starting from the centre) has twice as many houses as the previous one. Everybody will just walk along the spiral, which can be made as long as needed.

Comment: @klm123 How would you solve the spiral village then?

Comment: @Matta, go to the biggest group ($\sqrt{2}/2$), send each guy to another guy ($+\sqrt{2}$) and then send all back ($+\sqrt{2}/2$). $2\sqrt{2} < 2+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I think I have a proof that if there is a strategy that works in time $2+\sqrt 2$ for up to $2760$ people, then there is a strategy that works in this time for any number of people. Actually, as the number of people gets larger, the worst time converges down to $2\sqrt 2$, which happens when everybody live in two groups at two opposite corners of the square.

Comment: @mercio, why don't you try to minimize this number (I think even the strategy, which I show would always work with ~500 people) and post it as an answer? It is already better than nothing.

Comment: @klm123 Have you tried posting this on http://mathoverflow.net/ ?

Comment: In which competition was this problem used?

Comment: @Matta, no, duplicated questions are not allowed on SE. At most one can ask to move it there. But i'm not sure if it is appropriate, this is very specific problem.

Comment: @Servaes, just a local competition. It has no name.

Comment: Have you asked whomever gave you this problem for a solution? Because it seems incredibly difficult, and not in a way suitable for a competition.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but a proof that a good enough partial strategy for "few" villagers is sufficient.

If the only villagers are only located in two groups at two opposite corners of the square, then the best (and only) strategy takes time $2\sqrt 2 < 2+\sqrt 2$.

Suppose you have a not necessarily optimal strategy that takes time at most $T \ge 2+\sqrt 2$ to solve any square. (we know that those exist by the divide and conquer argument presented in the question)

If you can reach out to $n^2-1$ enough people in time $\frac 12 \sqrt 2 + \varepsilon$, then you can separate the square in $n^2$ small squares, use the strategy on the small squares, then return to the center, which gives you a strategy with a total time of $(\frac 12 \sqrt 2 + \varepsilon) + (1- \frac 1{2n})\sqrt 2 + \frac 1n T + (\frac 12 - \frac 1 {2n}) \sqrt 2$.

As $n \to \infty$, this converges down to $2\sqrt 2 +  \varepsilon$.
Under the assumption that given enough people in the square you can make $\varepsilon$ converge to $0$, you can start with any reasonable strategy and turn it into a new strategy whose worst time converges to $2\sqrt 2$ as the number of villagers gets large.

And from the previous worst-case examples, we know that $2\sqrt 2$, and the time $\frac 12 \sqrt 2 + \varepsilon$ are the best possible.

---

Now I will prove that if you have enough people in the square, then you can reach $N$ villagers in close to $\frac 12 \sqrt 2$ time.

Suppose you have $N$ villagers located in a tiny rectangular band of length $\frac 12 \sqrt 2$ and width $w$ and the headsman is starting in the middle of one extremities of the band.

Then by visiting every villager in order and branching, you can reach out to them in time at worst $\frac 12 \sqrt 2 + (\frac 12 + \lfloor \log_2(N) \rfloor )w$ : the amount of "zigzagging" needed is spread out to all the villagers thanks to the branching.

Finally, since the rectangle "covers" an angle of $2\arctan (w/\sqrt 2)$, you can cover a whole circle of radius $\sqrt 2/2$ with $\lceil \pi / \arctan (w / \sqrt 2) \rceil$ rectangles.

Therefore, if there is $\lceil \pi / \arctan (w / \sqrt 2) \rceil (N-1)+1$ villagers in total, then by the pigeonhole principle there is a band containing $N$ of them, and thus there is a way to reach out to $N$ villagers in time $\frac 12 \sqrt 2 + (\frac 12 + \lfloor \log_2(N) \rfloor )w$

---

Picking $n=5$ and $T = 2+\sqrt 2$ we obtain a recursive strategy that works in time $2+\sqrt 2$ as long as we can reach $24$ people in time $(16-5\sqrt 2)/10 = 0.892893\ldots$

To manage this we need bands with width $w = (8/5-\sqrt 2)/(\frac 12+4) = (16/5 - 2\sqrt 2)/9 = 0.041286\ldots$

So we need $108$ bands, and finally $2485$ villagers.

If you can devise a strategy that works in time $2+\sqrt 2$ for up to $2484$ villagers, then this method gives you a strategy that always works in this time.

Comment: up to $2484$ means it should work for $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots,10,11,\ldots,2484$ villagers. Then you can use that one to make a strategy that works for $2485$ and more villagers.

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give the algorithm first, then the proof.

1. The headman goes to the house nearest to him.
2. The headman makes the villager at that house a temporary headman.
3. Both the people at the house then go to the nearest **two** houses that have an unnotified villager that no one else is going to (i.e. if two headsmen are closest to the same house, the closer one will get it) and make each villager they meet a temporary headman.
4. The last step repeats until there are no more houses for them to go to. For instance, if there are five houses besides the headman's house, the headsman would go to the first house, then they would go to the second and third houses, and then two of the three people would go to the fourth and fifth house, but one of them would go to the town center.

As you pointed out with the houses at the four corners, $T_{MinMax}\ge2+\sqrt2$. However, because of the branching nature of this problem, adding another person to the mix generally reduces the time it takes. Consider the four houses again, but this time, add another house directly North of the headman's house. With this algorithm, the headman will visit this house to the North, then they will split up to visit the upper corners, then one of the two people currently at each of the upper corners will go directly South to the remaining two people and the other two people who have been visited will go directly to the middle of the town. This will take $\frac12+\frac12+1+\frac{\sqrt2}2=2+\frac{\sqrt2}2$ time total. Now, you could actually put that fifth house anywhere and it would still produce something less than $2+\sqrt2$. To see this, draw the original path, add another house, and draw a new house. You should be able to see that the original path is longer than the new path.

This is basically a proof by induction. You have two cases when you add a house:

**Case 1:** By the time you reach the extra house in the algorithm, you have enough people to cover the extra house without losing any time. This would be in the case with six or seven houses, as instead of the two people at the corners going back to the center of town, they would go pick up the other people. We know that they will not add any time by the triangle inequality, as the point where they meet and the two houses form a triangle and it will always be faster for them to split up and visit both places than for one to go back to town and the other person to take care of them both.

**Case 2:** The extra house introduces a branching point, as in the case with five houses as detailed earlier. In this case, adding an extra house can decrease the time if it is placed near the beginning of the run and increase it if it is placed at the end of the run. The closer you put that first branching point to the center of town, the more time you save, but doing so allows you more room to put that last branching point house, which allows you to increase the time. The farther you put it from the center of town, the less time you save, but you don’t have to go out of your way as much because the last house must be closer to the last corner.

I feel as if I'm missing something, so if anyone sees any errors, please let me know.

Comment: Imagine a spiral street. The distance between neighbouring turns being Epsilon. Houses are placed along the street in groups, the distance between groups being Epsilon/10. Each group (starting from the centre) has twice as many houses as the previous one. Everybody will just walk along the spiral, which can be made as long as needed.

Comment: @klm123 Do they have to follow the street or could they just walk across the group? Also, they can split up, correct?

Comment: what do you mean? The closest house will be always next house along the street, so your algorithm is forcing them to follow the street. May be i've missunderstood your algorithm? There are no constraints on their path in the problem condition itself.

Comment: @klm123 My algorithm deals with the closest **two** houses at every meeting. So what would end up happening is the headman goes to the first house, then the headman goes to the second house, but thenew head man would go to the third house or move up a layer. You end up with four headmen, who go to the next four houses, etc. Eventually, you will always end up with more headmen than houses in the layer, so they will end up on another layer, which will end up with even more headmen, etc.

Comment: This method is basically the method I asked about in the comments, which will fail every time you construct a village with a path where each next group of houses is twice as big, forcing *all* villagers to go to the next group each time, making the path and time as big as you like. This is resolved if you algorithm goes to the last group of houses (which is the one furthest away) and then you have enough villagers to take the rest from there. But your algorithm follows the CLOSEST house, not the OPTIMAL house as it should.

Comment: "Eventually, you will always end up with more headmen than houses in the layer" Why? Each group on the layer have exactly as many houses as there are headmen. Since Epsilon/10 << Epsilon this guaranties that all headmen will stay on the street. If I've misscalculated something, then just add more houses to the street.

Comment: @klm123 I misread that. I was thinking that after a certain point, some of the headmen would move onto another layer before finishing the other layer  because after a certain number of layers, the closest house to some headmen would be in another layer, as the distance between two of the unvisited houses in each layer would surpass the distance between two layers.